# Generic session variable key template helper with Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

How can I make the following helper more generic so that I can set arbitrary session vars with matching template vars and retrieve them without such a repetitive pattern?

```
Template.feedback5.helpers({
  'posX': function() {
    return Session.get('posX');
  },
  'dragPosition': function() {
    return Session.get('dragPosition');
  },
  'stuck': function() {
    return Session.get('stuck');
  },
  'dragging': function() {
    return Session.get('dragging');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register a global helper to get any Session variable given its key :

```
Template.registerHelper("getSession",function(key){
  return Session.get(key);
});
```

And use it like this in your Spacebars templates :

```
{{getSession "posX"}}
```

Comment: hey there - you mispelled Session... also is it worth doing `return Session.get(key) || null;` ? ie. will there be an exception if the var doesn't exist?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, trying to access a non existing Session variable will simply return undefined without raising an error so there's no need to check for it.